# Add delay after Platform.runLater runnable

Tags: java, javafx, delay

I'm really beginner with javaFX and probably I'm missing something, but here my issue: I should show some changes in my gui application sequentially.

My code looks like this (each method performs a change in the gui, but the final result is given by the last method of course):

```
public void updateGui()
{
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        doFirstStuff();
        doSecondStuff();
        doThirdStuff();
    });
}
```

It would be nice if between the execution of each method there was a little delay (1,2 or maybe 3 seconds) for give time to the user to see what happened in the application.

My attempt was put:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

after each method call, but since the thread is the JavaFX Application Thread, the result is awful.

Another solution that comes up right now in my mind is:

execute each method in another thread with a Runnable like this:

```
() -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        doFirstStuff();
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
});
```

and in `updateGui()` submit the task in a `newSingleThreadExecutor()` and wait for the termination of each task. But I don't know, it doesn't seem a good solution.

What is the best way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html):

```
public void updateGui() {
    final KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), e -> doFirstStuff());
    final KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> doSecondStuff());
    final KeyFrame kf3 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> doThirdStuff());
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(kf1, kf2, kf3);
    Platform.runLater(timeline::play);
}
```

I am assuming here that `updateGui()` is being called on a background thread (otherwise just remove `Platform.runLater(...)` and call `timeline.play()` directly).

If you really want to get your hands dirty with threads, you could achieve the same (more or less) with

```
public void updateGui() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Platform.runLater(() -> doFirstStuff());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Platform.runLater(() -> doSecondStuff());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Platform.runLater(() -> doThirdStuff());
        } catch (InterrupedException exc) {
            // should not be able to get here...
            throw new Error("Unexpected interruption");
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

but I think for use cases like this, the `Timeline` (or other parts of the animation API) are much cleaner (and use fewer resources, since they don't create a new thread).

Comment: How this is working? ' Platform.runLater(timeline::play); } '  first time seen it..

Comment: @GoXr3Plus It's a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). It's equivalent to `Platform.runLater(() -> timeline.play())`. Since the signature of `timeline.play()` (no params, no return value) is the same as the signature of the abstract method in `Runnable` you can simply pass a method reference in place of the implementation of `Runnable.run()`.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed! I tried both and even my `newSingleThreadExecutor()` solution, all works well for my purpose, but I guess `Timeline` way is the best for this kind of problems. Yes, I'm calling `updateGui()` from a background thread (maybe I should have specify, I'm sorry). Last thing: why the `final` modifier on `KeyFrames` and `Timeline`?

Comment: The `final` modifier is not necessary. The timeline and key frames are created on one thread and then accessed from another, so it's important that everything is done in a thread-safe manner. `KeyFrame`s are immutable, so if you force the references created to be final you are assured nothing is changed there, and the only access to the `Timeline` is via the constructor, which is effectively atomic. Modifying these with `final` doesn't guarantee I don't modify properties of the timeline later, but it is a good declaration of intent.