# Platform.runLater() - how to run multiple runnable element and get value

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, task

I need to execute 3 runnable instance in "serial" in other word, one by one but in the same thread, and get the result.

Currently my code is:

```
SendCommandTask sendLogReadCommand = new SendCommandTask(methodNameGetLog);
    sendLogReadCommand.setOnSucceeded(eventLog -> {
        this.LogTemp = ((List<Log>) sendLogReadCommand.getValue()).get(0);
        SendCommandTask sendSpaceReadCommand = new SendCommandTask(methodNameGetSpace);
        sendSpaceReadCommand.setOnSucceeded(eventSpace -> {
            this.boxTemp = ((List<BoxLabellTs>) sendSpaceReadCommand.getValue()).get(0);
            SendCommandTask sendAllLabellTssReadCommand = new SendCommandTask(methodNameGetAllLabellTss);
            this.listLabellTssTemp = (List<BotLabellTs>) sendAllLabellTssReadCommand.getValue();
            this.composeBox();              
        });
    });
    Platform.runLater(sendLogReadCommand);
```

Is there a way to run all with only one Platform.runLater command and get the result of each task?

Comment: The whole point of `Task` is to provide some ways getting some property changes from a background thread to the JavaFX application thread. `Platform.runLater` runs the task on the JavaFX application thread though; the `onSucceeded` handlers also run on the JavaFX application thread. You could simply execute all the tasks one after the other on the JavaFX application thread by calling the `run()` method and achieve the same effect.

Comment: In your implementation of `call()`, invoke `updateValue()` to indicate partial results; on the GUI, listen for the changing `value` property, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513).

Comment: I have a feeling you want it the other way round: create a Thread, do you longrunning stuff in your own thread and from that thread you call Platform.runlater() whenever you want to update the gui(only run the graphical stuff in the fx thread)

Answer (score 0):

Found!
[this link solve my problem:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235545/add-delay-after-platform-runlater-runnable?answertab=active#tab-top)

the code below is clean and it works!

```
public void updateGui() {
final KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), e -> doFirstStuff());
final KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> doSecondStuff());
final KeyFrame kf3 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> doThirdStuff());
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(kf1, kf2, kf3);
Platform.runLater(timeline::play);}
```

could be used also this:

`final Timeline timeline1 = new Timeline(kf1);
 final Timeline timeline2 = new Timeline(kf2);
 final Timeline timeline3 = new Timeline(kf3);
 SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition(timeline1, timeline2, timeline3);
Platform.runLater(sequence::play);`